# Moment and tail probability inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

How can I prove the following inequality:

> If $r>p$, then
>   \begin{equation}
>   \left\|X\right\|_{p}\le\left(\frac{r}{r-p}\right)^{1/p}\left\|X\right\| _{r,\infty},
>   \end{equation}
>   where
>   \begin{equation}
>   \left\|X\right\|_p=\left(\operatorname{E}\left|X\right|^p\right)^{1/p}\qquad\text{and}\qquad\left\|X\right\| _{r,\infty}=\left(\sup _{t>0}\ t^r\Pr\left(\left|X\right|>t\right) \right)^{1/r}.
>   \end{equation}

I found this inequality on page 10 of the book by [Ledoux and Talagrand](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/364220211X).

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The RHS is the upper bound of
$\displaystyle\|X\|_p^p=\mathrm E(|X|^p)=p\int_0^{+\infty}x^{p-1}\,\mathrm P(|X|\geqslant x)\,\mathrm dx
$
that one gets using the upper bound
$
\mathrm P(|X|\geqslant x)\leqslant\min\{1,\|X\|_{r,\infty}^rx^{-r}\}
$ for every $x\gt0$.